# How can I set up Active Directory user authentication?

Tags: windows, samba, pam

I am an Active Directory engineer, so not really a Linux savvy person.  I basically know enough to break a Linux workstation or server.

We have a team that needs to use Ubuntu workstations with their AD accounts.  I have been able to join an Ubuntu VM (the system I am writing this on) to my dev forest using this article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto

I have not been able to figure out how to get AD users to log on to the workstation.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Did you double check that you have winbind listed in your nsswitch.conf file for users and groups? What happens if you login with a local ID and do a "getent passwd " for one of your AD users? What does klist tell you (you may need to install krb5-utils).

First install winbind for AD logins, samba for domain connectivity and libpam-krb5 for Kerberos

```
sudo apt-get install winbind samba libpam-krb5
```

Then backup /etc/samba/smb.conf and create a new one with the following contents:

```
[global]
workgroup = DOMAIN
security = ADS
realm = AD.DOMAIN.COM
```

Run "testparm" to make sure your smb.conf file is not messed up and then change to a root interactive shell

```
  sudo -i
```

Now add the machine to the domain

```
   net ads join -U username
```

Assuming DNS is set up properly & you're on the network with your DC's it should prompt you for username's password and add the PC to the domain. If you get an error about DNS don't worry about it.